# jQuery fontsize editation when depending on height of window

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make font-size smaller when window of browser is smaller too but it doesn't work... I'm also trying to make some divs smaller but it doesn't work too... Can you help me? Anyway, Chrome doesn't write any error...
Here's my code:

jQuery:

```
if($(window).width() < 720 ) {
    $('.menulink').height(7);
    $(".middlepagediv" && ".leftoverdiv" && ".leftdiv" && ".rightoverdiv" && ".rightdiv").height('480px');
    }
else if($(window).width() > 720 < 1440 ) {
    $(".middlepagediv" && ".leftoverdiv" && ".leftdiv" && ".rightoverdiv" && ".rightdiv").height('1020px');
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul class="mmenu">
<li onclick="onas()"><div class="menulink">O nás
</div></li><li onclick="produkty()"><div class="menulink">Produkty
</div></li><li onclick="aplikace()"><div class="menulink">Aplikace
</div></li><li onclick="sluzby()"><div class="menulink">Služby
</div></li><li><div class="menulink inactive"><a href="/downloads/content.htm" class="inactive">Ke stažení</a></div></li><li><div class="menulink inactive"><a href="/News/content.htm" class="inactive">Novinky</a></div></li><li><div class="menulink"><a href="/about/contacts/content.htm" target="maincnt">Kontakty</a></div></li></ul>
<br>
<div class="overline">
<ul id="lower"><li><p class="menulink"><a href="/about/about/content.htm" target="maincnt">O nás</a></p></li><li><p class="menulink"><a href="/about/reference/content.htm" target="maincnt">Reference</a></p></li><li><p class="menulink"><a href="/about/contacts/content.htm" target="maincnt">kontakty</a></p></li></ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Have a look at [jQuery Multiple Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and there is no need for the `> 720` in your else if as that is asserted by the first statement.

Comment: Also if you could provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the html/css/js that would help.

Comment: I cannot provide it... Because I have XML file, and lots of other files that is functionality depending at...

Comment: Ok, can you not replicate a basic version of what you are trying to achieve? Just the html and jQuery should be enough.

Comment: I gave it to post I'M not sure what you wanted...

Comment: He asks you to create a [self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) without your specific dependencies. This enables him to replicate the behaviour and suggest a fix. A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
window.addEventListener( 'resize', function( event ) {
```

ect to trigger during each window size shift. Example:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
  if ($(window).width() < 720) {
    $('.menulink').css('font-size', '7em');
    $(".middlepagediv, .leftoverdiv, .leftdiv, .rightoverdiv, .rightdiv").css('font-size', '4em');
  } else if ($(window).width() > 720 < 1440) {
    $(".middlepagediv, .leftoverdiv, .leftdiv, .rightoverdiv, .rightdiv").css('font-size', '2em');
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.menulink {
  font-size: 3em;
}
.middlepagediv {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="menulink">Menu Link</p>
<p class="middlepagediv">Mid Page</p>
```